# How to select rows in every day between two dates using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to keep track of users logged in every day between two dates.
Let's say I have a table `my_table` like this:

| user_id | login_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 10:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-10-02 12:20:00 |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 17:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-10-04 22:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-10-04 23:00:00 |

and given date range is from '2021-10-02' to '2021-10-04'.

I want to get user_id = 1 in this case, because user_id = 2 is not logged in at '2021-10-03'

result

| user_id | login_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 |
| 1 | 2021-10-04 |

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM my_table
WHERE login_datetime >= '2021-10-02' AND login_datetime < '2021-10-05'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(login_datetime)) = 3;  -- range has 3 dates in it
```

### Demo

The `HAVING` clause asserts that any matching user must have 3 distinct dates present, which would imply that such a user would have login activity on all dates from 2021-10-02 to 2021-10-04 inclusive.

**Edit:**

To get the exact output in your question, you may use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, DATE(login_datetime) AS login_date
FROM my_table
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE login_datetime >= '2021-10-02' AND login_datetime < '2021-10-05'
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(login_datetime)) = 3
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have a question. Is there any solution to get the table result like above?

Comment: @Silverstar I guess I missed your expected output.  Check my updated answer for one way to do this.

Comment: Note that in practice, if you were calling this query from an application (e.g. Java or PHP), you might actually want to use the first version.  Once you get a matching `user_id`, you automatically know that this user matched for the entire date range, so having SQL do more work to regenerate this range is potentially wasted computing time.  Just a thought `:-)`

Comment: yes. I agree. you are right. The second query is not important. Just I was wanted to get a formulated table.